# ini-parser add key in a for loop

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ini

hi can anyone please help me? im trying to add a some keys with ini-parser, but i only get the last index of the loop.

```
        var parser = new FileIniDataParser();
        IniData data = parser.ReadFile("devreorder.ini");

        foreach (DeviceInstance di in Manager.GetDevices(DeviceClass.GameControl, EnumDevicesFlags.AttachedOnly))
        {
           
            data["ALL"].AddKey("\"" + di.ProductName + "\"", "{" + di.InstanceGuid + "}");
            
        }
        parser.WriteFile("devreorder.ini", data);
```

i could put the WriteFile in the loop, but that feels wrong to me.

Comment: What is `data` and what are you trying to do? Without knowing what you expect and what you are getting is going to make it difficult to proffer a solution.

Comment: sorry,  data is the parsed ini file, i took it from the examples in the ini-parser wiki: https://github.com/rickyah/ini-parser/wiki/First-Steps
the foreach loop is a list of connected hid devices, im just trying to put the name and guid in the ini file under [ALL] section.

Comment: Where does `devnum` come from?  It doesn't seem to change ever, which is why you only get one value of `devnum` written in the file.

Comment: devnum is something else im doing, it has nothing to do with this loop , i will delete it to avoid confusion.
the problem is i have 3 devices showing in this loop, and if i assign them to a string i will get 3 lines, but when i use the addkey function it only happens once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing that could really help you debug is to go from DeviceInstance enumeration to `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`, and then in a separate loop use the list of pairs to update the INI file.

```
var devenum = Manager.GetDevices(DeviceClass.GameControl, EnumDevicesFlags.AttachedOnly);
var keyvalues = devenum.Select(di => new KeyValuePair<string, string>("\"" + di.ProductName + "\"(" + devnum + ")", "{" + di.InstanceGuid + "}")).ToList();
     
//readfile here   
foreach (var kvp in keyvalues)
{
    data["ALL"].AddKey(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);        
}
//writefile here
```

The first part could even be done before ever touching the file.  And you will be able to inspect the list contents in the debugger, then if something is wrong, you won't blame the INI parser.

I suspect your problem stems from `devnum` being the same for all devices.  If that's the issue, it will be clearly shown in `keyvalues`.